# How to replace a img element with a very similar gif element at its exact position at all times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

In my code, an  element is randomly generated anywhere in the body and when it's clicked, it's replaced with another gif element. I use offset() to get the top and left values of the image first, and then use replaceWith() to replace it with the gif, and use css() to specify the left and top values of the gif like so:

```js
function randomInt(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

var thewidth = randomInt(1,1000);

$("body").prepend( "<img src='red_dot.png' class='enemies' id='enemy' left:thewidth/2 + 'px'></img>");

var n = $("#enemy").offset();
    console.log(n.left);
    console.log(n.top);
    $("#enemy").click(function()
    {
      $("#enemy").replaceWith("<img src='explosion.gif' id = 'explosion'></img>");
      $("#explosion").css({"left" : n.left+'px', "top" : n.top + "px"});
```

```css
.enemies
{
  position: fixed;
  transform: scale(0.01,0.01);
}

#explosion
{
  transform: scale(0.1,0.1);
  position: fixed;
}
```

As you can see, both positions are fixed. When I run this, the img and gif are at different positions, and I logged the top and left values to the console to check if they're the same and they are. Why are they at different positions then and how do I make it so that the gif replaces the image at its exact position always?

Comment: Where is `thewidth` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 its a global variable generated with a math.random() based function previously.

Comment: Have you tried just replacing the attributes instead of the whole element?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha `thewidth` is not defined at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: i'm with @GeneParcellano: why aren't you just replacing the src. it seems like you're going through a lot of trouble for something simple.

Comment: @guest271314 I added the origin of the var. Oh yeah, replacing the src of the image is a better idea. Tring that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html` is missing `style` attribute at `<img>` element, which is self-closing. Use `calc()` at `left` property value to set `thewidth`, use same value at `.replaceWith()` call.

Alternatively, use `jQuery()`, as suggested by @GeneParcellano replace `src`, `id` attributes of same element with `.attr()`, chain `.removeClass()` to remove `"enemies"` `.className` at element.

```js
function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var thewidth = randomInt(1, 1000);

$("body")
.prepend(
  $("<img />", { 
    src :"http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats",
    "class": "enemies",
    id:"enemy",
    css: {
      left: "calc(" + thewidth / 2 + "px)"
    }})
  );

$("#enemy").click(function() {
  $(this)
  .attr({
     "src": "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature"
  ,  "id": "explosion"
  })
  .removeClass("enemies");
});
```

```css
.enemies {
  position: fixed;
  /*transform: scale(0.01, 0.01);*/
}
#explosion {
  /*transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);*/
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mL1y1qk5/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, and yes, I'm going with the alternative of changing the src and it worked well. Edit: one more thing, how do I assign a counter variable along with the id in the prepend statement? Because$("body").prepend("<img src='red_dot.png' class='enemies' id='enemy'+i style='left:calc(" + thewidth/2 + "px)'/>"); doesnt seem to work, that is, the id isnt becoming #enemy1.

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha You can concatenate `i` to string at `jQuery()` `attributes` object `id:"enemy" + i`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the transform origin property to the enemies class to set the origin of image to the top instead of center of image.

```
.enemies{
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

Also set it for in css property of explosion id as well.